# Redirect old domain to new one 500 error (OpenCart)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, opencart

Hi I'm trying to redirect the old domain to the new one. The setup is based on OpenCart. When I add the following lines I get a 500 server error:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC
```

What is already in .htaccess: There may be a conflict in the 301 rules

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/ [R=301]
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]

# OpenCart SEO
RewriteRule  ^contact\/?$  index.php?route=information/contact  [L] #Contact Page
ReWriteRule  ^home\/$  index.php?route=common/home [L] #Home Page

RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `]` on the last line.

Comment: Still get the same error even when I add the closing bracket. I think I missed the bracket when I was copy pasting it here, apologies

Comment: What other directives do you have in your file? Where exactly are you placing these new directives?

Comment: Added the rest to the description

Comment: And where are you placing these directives in your file?

Comment: ...it would need to go immediately after the `RewriteEngine On` directive. Just to clarify, are `olddomain.com` and `newdomain.com` pointing to the same host?

Comment: I managed to sort the issue by using the redirect facility that was provided by cPanel, not sure why would that work and not adding the lines in manually, thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. There's no great reason for cPanel's version to work and yours not to, other than maybe positioning in the file or perhaps strange characters in the source. A 500 error is usually the result of a fundamental error in the syntax, but there is no evidence of that in the code you have posted. To be honest, cPanel usually causes more problems than it solves in this respect!

Comment: Totally agree with you but I'm just happy it's all working.